# Fetch an input file dynamically in a batch file to perform operations on it

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have created a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which uses [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) to extract frames of a video to `.jpg`.

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4  -r 5 E:\frames\createdFrames%%d.jpg
```

It works completely fine and created the desired frames, however  I want to give the sample video dynamically, i.e. pass it when the batch file is being executed.

How can I pass the input file dynamically?

If possible, also discuss how to store the file dynamically, i.e pass the directory where I want to store the file when the batch is being executed.

Comment: use parameters: `ffmpg -i "%~1" -r 5 "%~2\createdFrames%%d.jpg"` (just guessing your intentions, as the question isn't clear)

Comment: As mentioned above i am trying to create frames of a video using ffmpeg. The above mentioned command( ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -r 5 E:\frames\createdFrames%%d.jpg ) is working fine when i am passing the name of the video file which is stored in the same folder as batch file. Now i want to pass the input file (Sample.mp4 in this case ) Dynamically i.e when i executes the batch file i'll be able to pass the input video's name dynamically.

Comment: We cannot help you if we do not know what you want us to help you with. Are you wanting to ask for the user to input the filename from within the script itself or are you wanting to run the script with the filename as an input argument/parameter, _(both mentioned in my previous comment)_. Technically you should not post a fully working script sample asking for somebody to bolt onto it a new feature. We're not here to write scripts for you to order, you are supposed to write your own code and post here a [mcve] of the failing part of the code explaining the specific issue it is exhibiting.

Comment: i need to pass a video to the batch file at the time of running rather than hardcoding it into the batch file.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i "%1" -r 5 E:\frames\createdFrames%%d.jpg` and `mybatch.bat filename.mp4`

Comment: Yup it is working , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "infile=%~1"
set "outdir=%~2"
if not defined infile set /p "infile=Input file: " || exit /b 1
if not defined outdir set /p "outdir=Output dir: " || exit /b 2
if not exist "%outdir%" md "%outdir%" || exit /b 3
ffmpeg -i "%infile%" -r 5 "%outdir%\createdFrames%%d.jpg"
```

Can pass arguments to the batch-file, e.g. `batch.bat sample.mp4 E:\frames`

If no argument is passed, a input prompt will ask for a input file. If not defined, will exit. Same happens with input of output directory.

The output directory is created if needed and exits if fails.

If all OK, runs the `ffmpeg` command.